# TypeError: to_excel() got multiple values for argument 'sheet_name'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to save different dataframes to different worksheets as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import xlsxwriter

// code
bio         = BytesIO()
with pd.ExcelWriter(bio, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    dfStats.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
    dfStockdata.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='HistoricalISIN')

# create the workbook
writer.save() // tried both with and without this line
bio.seek(0)
workbook    = bio.read()
excelFile   = workbook
```

However, I am receiving the following error:

```
TypeError: to_excel() got multiple values for argument 'sheet_name'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Its nice if your code would run after copy + paste, so add the imports :) It might be due to the fact that you use the normal ExcelWriter and not the pandas.ExcelWriter?

Comment: `sheet_name='Summary'` and `sheet_name='HistoricalISIN'` first value is `filename` ?

Comment: Is using BytesIO a requirement?

Comment: I am using pandas excelwriter. Will update the code desc. Using BytesIO is a requirement yes.

Comment: See: Writing Excel Files to Memory on: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output//out.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
dfStats.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
dfStockdata.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='HistoricalISIN')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Yes, but that will save the file locally. I am trying to avoid that, thus to save it using BytesIO.

Comment: Note. I tried to do it like you said and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: Strange, this code (with different dfs and sheet names) works for me. Which pandas version are you using?

Comment: version 0.19.2 with python3

Comment: I figured it out. dfStockdata consisted of multiple "sheets". So I removed the sheet_name attribute and then it printed multiple sheets instead of 2

Comment: Great! Good that you found the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I tested with some sample data and it works as expected:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

bio = BytesIO()

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [11, 12, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Data': [21, 22, 23, 24]})

with pd.ExcelWriter(bio, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Summary')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='HistoricalISIN')

with open('pandas_file.xlsx', 'wb') as w:
    w.write(bio.getvalue())
```

Output:

[image]

Versions:

```
Python:     Python 2.7.13 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
xlsxwriter: 0.9.6
pandas:     0.19.2
```